# Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1 + flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, path, environment-variables

I have been trying to install Flutter in my windows Pc. In the enviroment variables I added: C:/src/bin, C:src/bin/flutter_console.bat to allow special access and yet I keep recieving this error. Basically, there is no file named flutter.exe or flutter_console.exe, although I found dart.exe. So I am unable to install flutter properly. Even if I specify the path to this flutter sdk directory, or even its bin directory in Android Studio, it says no flutter-sdk found in specified location. If anymore details required, I can provide.

Exception: Cannot run program "C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" (in directory "C:\src\flutter"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJbOq.png)